# How can I check a 3x3 square on my sudoku in C#?

Tags: c#

I was able to check my row and my column and my sudoku starts like that(having a background)

```
public Sudoku()
{
   player = 0;
   IsComplete = false;
   Grid = new int[9, 9];
}

public bool IsValidSquare(int col, int row) 
{
    bool IsValid = true;
    int counter = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) 
        {
            if (Grid[i, j] == Grid[i, j])
                IsValid = false;
        }
    }

    return IsValid;
}
```

I tried to create a function that allows me to check the 3x3 inputs. I started like that but I know it is wrong and I think I need a counter. Can you help me?

Comment: `if (Grid[i, j] == Grid[i, j])`  Wouldn't this always be true?

Comment: Can you say more precisely what condition makes a 3x3 square "valid"? Solve this problem by first writing in natural language a *specification* for the function: what, precisely, is its intended behavior?  Once you have a correct specification, then you can do two things (1) write test cases which verify the specification, and (2) write code which carefully translates the specification into code.  Then run the tests and find out if you were right.

Comment: Another technique for solving this sort of problem is to solve an easier version of the problem. For example: can you write the method with specification "this method returns true if the 3x3 square contains EXACTLY ONE square with a 9 in it, and false otherwise" ?  If you cannot write that function, then you cannot write the harder version. But if you can write that function, then you can use it as a starting point for writing the harder version. If you're stuck solving a hard problem, **find a simpler related problem** and solve that.

Comment: Which definition of "valid" are you trying to implement? A)  "This 3x3 square contains exactly 1 of each number 1-9" or B) "This 3x3" does not contain any duplicates" ? The latter is useful for offering a local check of intermediate solve state whereas the former is useful for checking a completed solution.

Comment: A third technique (which I use frequently) is to consider the problem not as a classification problem (square is "valid" or "invalid") but rather an *explanation* problem. Suppose your code had to not just classify the validity, but explain why it was invalid. Your sudoku program might have to do that! It would be nice to have it say "this solution is invalid because there is more than one 9 in this square", rather than "this solution is invalid".  Considering what messages you might generate motivates a decomposition of the problem into easier subproblems you can spec, solve and test.

Answer (score 0):

Check () checks the rules for rows, columns and the 3x3 fields. Parameter field is your 9x9 Grid, x is the column, y is the row and value is the value you want to set. Returns true if the input complies with the rules.

```
private bool check(int[,] field, int x, int y, int value)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        if (field[i, y] == value && i != x) return false;
        if (field[x, i] == value && i != y) return false;
        int cx = (x / 3) * 3 + (i % 3);
        int cy = (y / 3) * 3 + (i / 3);
        if (field[cx, cy] == value && cx != x && cy != y)  return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Maybe that's the solution to your question.

Comment: Thank you, can you explain the last part int cx=(x/3) *3(i%3); I don't understand

Comment: public bool IsValidCol(int col)
        {
            bool isValid = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            {
                for (int j = i + 1; j < 9; j++)
                {
                    if (Grid[i, col] == Grid[j, col])
                        isValid = false;
                }
            }
            return isValid;
        } (I did that to check the column for example and another function for row)

Comment: `(x/3) * 3` maps `012345678` to `000333666` using integer rounding .  `+ (i%3)` maps `+ 012345678` to `+ 012012012` using mod.  So if you're trying to check a specific x coordinate, this will end up checking the 3 horizontal columns corresponding to that coordinate 3 times each (i.e., because each 3x3 block has 3 numbers per column).

Comment: `(x / 3) * 3` and `(y / 3) * 3` calculate the upper left corner for the 3x3 field in which x, y lies. `(i % 3)` and `(i / 3)` calculate the X offset and the Y offset in the 3x3 field.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a heavily commented/documented implementation of `IsValidSquare`.  I tried to make the functionality is obvious/clear as possible.  Note that I changed the signature to pass in a `grid` as a parameter, but this isn't required.

Notes:

- I didn't bother to force the lines to be narrow enough for a Stackoverflow code block.  Sorry.
- I didn't pay any attention to standard naming conventions.
- This is code goes rather extreme in error-checking and in documentation.  This is done for pedagogical purposes, but may be excessive in production code.

```
void Main()
{
    var test = new int[9, 9];
    /* I could implement this in a for loop, but half the reason I want to test this code is to
     * ensure that I implemented my loops properly in IsValidSquare
     * As an implementation detail, I know that IsValidSquare won't pay attention to 
     * things outside the square
     */

    test[0, 0] = 1;
    test[0, 1] = 2;
    test[0, 2] = 3;
    test[1, 0] = 4;
    test[1, 1] = 5;
    test[1, 2] = 6;
    test[2, 0] = 7;
    test[2, 1] = 8;
    test[2, 2] = 9;

    //1-9
    Console.WriteLine($"Should be True: {IsValidSquare(test, 1, 1)}");
    test[2, 2] = 8;

    //Has an 8 in 2,1 and 2,2
    Console.WriteLine($"Should be False: {IsValidSquare(test, 1, 1)}");

    test[2,1] = 9;
    //Has an 9 in 2,1 and an 8 in 2,2
    Console.WriteLine($"Should be True: {IsValidSquare(test, 1, 1)}");

    try
    {
        IsValidSquare(test, 2, 10);
        Console.WriteLine("Oops! We didn't throw an exception");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception Success! " + ex.Message.Replace("\r\n", "\t"));
    }

    try
    {
        IsValidSquare(test, 2, -5);
        Console.WriteLine("Oops! We didn't throw an exception");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception Success! " + ex.Message.Replace("\r\n", "\t"));
    }

    try
    {
        IsValidSquare(test, -2, 5);
        Console.WriteLine("Oops! We didn't throw an exception");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception Success! " + ex.Message.Replace("\r\n", "\t"));
    }

    try
    {
        IsValidSquare(new int[5,5], 2, 2);
        Console.WriteLine("Oops! We didn't throw an exception");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception Success! " + ex.Message.Replace("\r\n", "\t"));
    }

}

///<Summary>Check that a 3x3 block within <c>grid</c> contains exactly 1 of each 1-9</Summary>
///<param name="grid">A 9x9 grid of integers</param>
///<param name="col">A 0-indexed column of a 3x3 sub-grid within the 9x9 grid of integers.  </param>
///<param name="row">A 0-indexed row of a 3x3 sub-grid within the 9x9 grid of integers.  </param>
///<returns>True if the 3x3 sub-grid contains exactly 1 of each 1-9</returns>
public static bool IsValidSquare(int[,] grid, int col, int row)
{
    /* Here, I use self-documenting exceptions.  Each exception makes all of the following clear:
     • Which argument caused the exception
     • Whether there is a bug in the caller or in IsValidSquare (Argument Exceptions indicate a bug in the caller)
     • What was wrong with the input (either via the exception type or the exception message
     • I use nameof to ensure that exception parameters match parameter names.  If someone renames a parameter, exceptions will be kept up-to-date.
     • All exceptions correspond to instructions within the function documentation
    */
    if (grid == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(grid));
    }
    
    if (grid.GetLength(0) != 9 || grid.GetLength(1) != 9) {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(grid), "Grid should be a 9x9 Grid. ");
    }

    if (col < 0 || col >= 9)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(col), "Argument must be between 0 and 8. ");
    }

    if (row < 0 || row >= 9)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(row), "Argument must be between 0 and 8. ");
    }

    /* Force row/column to be the top-left corner of the 3x3 block
     * It's up to the spec author how this should work.  For example, your specification could require the row/column to be the top-left corner of the 3x3 block.
     */
    col = col / 3 * 3;  //Get the leftmost cell in a 3 column block
    row = row / 3 * 3;  //Get the topmost cell in a 3 row block

    HashSet<int> used = new HashSet<int>();

    //Handle 3 columns: col, col+1, and col+2
    for(var i = col; i < col+3;++i)
    {
        //Handle 3 rows: row, row+1, and row+2
        for (var j = row; j < row+3; ++j)
        {
            //If there is anything other than 1-9, we treat the solution as invalid.
            //It is up to the spec author whether such a solution should be considered invalid or
            //should crash as malformed data.
            if(grid[i,j] < 1 || grid[i,j] > 9)
            {
                return false;
            }
            
            //Per learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.add
            //used.Add will return false if we add an element that was previously added.
            if (!used.Add(grid[i,j]))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    //Adding an assert since I'm pretending not to trust the above code.
    Debug.Assert(used.Count == 9, "I thought the above code would always add 9" + 
        "  numbers, but it turns out I was wrong.");

    return true;

}
```